# Script tags to embed Dart into HTML

Tags: dart

Normally Dart is connected to HTML by means of this code:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="script.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

By running Build, IntellijIdea transforms the first line into `<script src="script.dart.js">` and eliminates the second line, OK. But there are some problems to me:

1. After Build file has been created, my indentation is broken.
2. Google PageSpeed Insight test says "Too much http requests", or something like that.

I solved the problem this way. No Build file anymore, I use Dart2js + Terminal to create script.dart.js. As to the HTML code, I've written this little thing below instead.

```
<script type="application/dart" src="script.dart" id="dart-script"></script>
<script>
  (function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('(Dart)') === -1) {
      var dartScript = document.querySelector('#dart-script');
      dartScript.type = 'application/javascript';
      dartScript.src = 'script.dart.js';
    }
  })();
</script>
```

It works very well. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of any such problems with the Dart script tags.

Using the transformer of https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter 
removes the Dart script tag which is only required by browsers that support Dart directly, which is only Dartium, which is not supposed to be used to access the web (only for development purposes), therefore for deployment this script tag is irrelevant.

Comment: The page you linked to sums up the problem I tried to solve. I think IntelliJIdead uses Dart_to_js_script_rewriter to make the Build duplicate file.

My goal was very simple: only one unique website file (no Build at all) and the same HTML polyvalent pages able to work both with Dart (in Dartium) or JS (anywhere else) without any manipulation while optimizing speed performances at the same time. I think my little script above does the job (we could write directly the original dart.js into HTML too).

Comment: It's great if your script works for you. I doubt though, WebStorm does anything you claim it does. WebStorm only calls `pub build`. If you don't have the transformer mentioned in my answer then there should be nothing that does the rewrite.

Comment: I don't speak of WebStorm, for Dart I use IntelliJIdea CE and I don't like my indentation to be moved upside-down. Thank you for your reply, I think the topic is over.

Comment: Sorry, AFAIK in regard to this topic WebStorm and IntelliJ behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Dart plugin is the same in IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm and other JetBrains' IDEs. And it doesn't do anything with your source code on build, it only calls `pub build` as if you ran it from command line (assume you are talking about 'Pub: build' action in context of `pubspec.yaml` file).

Answer (score 0):

I'll stop here my delirium with this new polyvalent code of my own.

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var elem = document.createElement('script');
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(elem);
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('(Dart)') === -1) {
      elem.type = 'application/javascript';
      elem.src = 'script.dart.js';
    }
    else {
      elem.type = 'application/dart';
      elem.src = 'script.dart';
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Thank you for applause, that's all folks!